# Ionic cordova build android error fail to export

Tags: ionic-framework

i'm trying to publish my first app with Ionic for Android, I use :

```
cordova build android --release
```

But it shows this error :

| Running command [19:52:24]  lint finished in 21.58 s
× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --release (exit code 1):

```
    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112
    Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
    :wrapper

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 16s
    1 actionable task: 1 executed
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use
    Task.doLast(Action) instead.
            at build_79qurmse68iuc8ksfkmhnwhsg.run(D:\IONIC\Projects\myFirstApp\platforms\android\build.gradle:137)

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'.
        > A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
           > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
              > Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
                Required by:
                    project :CordovaLib
                 > Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
                    > Could not get resource
    'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'.
                       > Could not GET
    'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'.
                          > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed:
    Connection timed out: connect

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 32.287 secs
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'.
        > A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
           > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
              > Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
                Required by:
                    project :CordovaLib
                 > Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
                    > Could not get resource
    'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'.
                       > Could not GET
    'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'.
                          > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed:
    Connection timed out: connect

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Not sure why Ionic would need the Bintray plugin. Also not sure this is an Android-related question in the first place, as Ionic is not in Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the android_home class path has been set correctly

Comment: when i type ```android``` in cmd, it opens android sdk manager, is that correct?